# Weird issues with timthumb

Tags: php

I am having the wierdest issues with timthumb.php it was working great i had it resizing all my images then suddenly it stop working for a certain set of image???

Can anyone shed some light on this i have been stuck for hours trying to figure this out???

ok here is a working image link.
http://gladtohelpyou.com/wp-content/themes/huddle/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=http://gladtohelpyou.com/users/5/images/Random%20Pics/Screenshot2012-01-24at16.35.04.png&a=t&h=65&w=65&q=100

As you can see that link works fine and it will resize for me great but if i try to load this image in the same folder i get this.
http://gladtohelpyou.com/wp-content/themes/huddle/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=http://gladtohelpyou.com/users/5/images/rings/b_IMG_5907%20Mission%20Photographic.jpg&a=t&h=65&w=65&q=100

ok where i am stuck is i can load the full image find.
http://gladtohelpyou.com/users/5/images/rings/b_IMG_5907%20Mission%20Photographic.jpg

it is doing that for all of those images but all the other images are working fine i have tried uploading large file sizes change the name, cant think of what else to try.

Has anyone had similar issues

Ok still working on this if i use wordpresses built in upload for those specific image types i get the following error.

```
Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Passed data is not in 'JPEG' format in /home/justimages/public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 258
```

can anyone let me know why this is happening are my images corrupted???

Comment: Try getting rid of the spaces in the photo name. Rename it and see if it works.

Comment: The timthumb error message is not particularily helpful. Have you checked the file exists, is accessible and is actually a valid JPG file? Probably you can link the original picture?

Comment: hi thanks for the responses tried both of those first things i tried i have renamed it lower case no spaces etc still nothing and the file definitely exists because its here http://gladtohelpyou.com/users/5/images/rings/b_IMG_5907%20Mission%20Photographic.jpg really strange

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your webhost isn't banning that script at the server level.  On Friday, Jan 27th, 2012 Westhost (www.westhost.com) disabled timthumb across all it's shared servers and now my WooThemes-based Child Theme is non-functional for external images (read: Youtube screenshots).

Make sure your webhost didn't ban the script outright.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions on the set of images that aren't working?  Are they the same as the images that do work?  They may be owned by a different user or group?

(I don't have permission to post comments yet, so posting this as an answer)